# Google play services out of date. Requires 5089000 but found 3136130

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to use Google cloud messaging for an android app (Target name: `Google APIs`, platform: `4.3`, API level: `18`.

I implemented my GCM client by following the isntructions here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html,

and setup play services by following the steps here:
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup, but still get the above error

Most of the solutions I've found on stack overflow redirect to the above two links, or suggest that we change the `dependencies {}` in the gradle settings, but I'm using eclipse and don't have gradle setup.

*Update:*  Sorry yes I'm using the emulator and not a device

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using an emulator for testing this?

Comment: where are you getting this error..? logcat?

Comment: yes I'm using an emulator and getting the error in logcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final solution was creating a new emulator under Android 4.4.2, with the build target of the project set to Google APIs (x86 System Image). Thanks to Pedro Oliveira!

Answer (score 3):

If you need to provide an option for the user to update the google services you can do this:

```
   switch (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)) {
        case 2: //out date
            try {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(2, this, 0).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

    }
```

This will prompt an update dialog for the user to update play services

Comment: Hi since I'm using the emulator I get a popup asking me to update but when I click on update nothing happens

Comment: That's because it's an emulator. You have to create a new emulator with the new google api version. Remember to update your SDK first

Comment: In my SDK manager, I have Android 4.4.2 (API 19), ANdroid 4.4W (API 20), and Android L (API 20) not currently installed - which one should I install?

Comment: You need to use a Google API system image

Comment: Thank you! The final solution was creating a new emulator under Android 4.4.2, with the build target of the project set to Google APIs (x86 System Image)