# Unable to locate play service on android emulator extended controls on android studio 3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

[image]

I am getting error in android studio, where the solution is to update the android play service, but I am unable to locate it in extended controls. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you post the actual error you're getting?

Comment: @WadeWilson Getting this error Message "W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11717000 but found 11577470"

Comment: Is that error from running your app or is it a message from Android Studio itself.

Comment: Its while i am running the app

Comment: I believe you need to create an Emulator image with Google Play Service. It should automatically update the serivces like a real device does with an active internet connection. View this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597974/android-places-api-google-play-services-out-of-date-on-emulator

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @WadeWilson Not exactly solution but i created new virtual device Nexus 5x where play service is available, it worked then

Comment: That's what I recommended. I think you old Emulator image didn't have Google Play Services installed. So creating a new one with the Google play Services installed fixed the problem. As long as you give the emulator internet connectivity it should update itself with the most recent Play services version like a real android device.