# Google Maps Api v2 Android Error

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services, android-4.2-jelly-bean

only Android 5.0 work.
Error by Android 5.0 lower

I have installed all SDK package.

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.allegretti.triestebus" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.allegretti.triestebus.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />







    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Triestebus" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.grade

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.allegretti.triestebus"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

Java class

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
     MapView mMap;
     GoogleMap googleMap;
    View rootView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

       rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);
        mMap = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        mMap.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        googleMap = mMap.getMap();
//        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
//        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


        // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());

        // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
//        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(45.649526, 13.776818), 13);
       // googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);



      /*  googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(45.631523, 13.780745)).title("Fermata di Via Svevo").snippet("1-8-29-B"));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(45.641204, 13.774329)).title("Fermata di Via Leon Battista Alberti").snippet("29-B"));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(45.628215, 13.820757)).title("Fermata di Via Alpi Giulie").snippet("37-48-C"));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(45.639983, 13.758070)).title("Fermata di Passeggio Sant'Andrea").snippet("8-9-A"));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(45.627767, 13.810545)).title("Fermata di Via Erta Sant'Anna").snippet("34"));
*/
        return (rootView);

    }
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        mMap.onResume();

    }

    @Override

    public void onPause() {

        super.onPause();

        mMap.onPause();

    }

    @Override

    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

        mMap.onDestroy();

    }

    @Override

    public void onLowMemory() {

        super.onLowMemory();

        mMap.onLowMemory();

    }







}
```

EROR

```
VFY: unable to resolve instance field 16
04-15 16:23:18.943    1791-1791/com.allegretti.triestebus D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x00b3
04-15 16:23:18.953    1791-1791/com.allegretti.triestebus E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
04-15 16:23:18.953    1791-1791/com.allegretti.triestebus W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 25 (Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;
04-15 16:23:18.953    1791-1791/com.allegretti.triestebus D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000e
04-15 16:23:18.963    1791-1791/com.allegretti.triestebus I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzg
04-15 16:23:18.963    1791-1791/com.allegretti.triestebus W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 497: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
04-15 16:23:18.963    1791-1791/com.allegretti.triestebus D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
04-15 16:23:18.983    1791-1791/com.allegretti.triestebus W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7095000 but found 3136130
04-15 16:23:18.993    1791-1791/com.allegretti.triestebus W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7095000 but found 3136130
04-15 16:23:19.033    1791-1791/com.allegretti.triestebus W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7095000 but found 3136130
04-15 16:23:19.043    1791-1791/com.allegretti.triestebus W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7095000 but found 3136130
04-15 16:23:19.053    1791-1791/com.allegretti.triestebus W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7095000 but found 3136130
```

Google Maps Api v2 Android Error
 Google Maps Api v2 Android Error Google Maps Api v2 Android Error Google Maps Api v2 Android Error Google Maps Api v2 Android Error Google Maps Api v2 Android Error Google Maps Api v2 Android Error Google Maps Api v2 Android Error Google Maps Api v2 Android Error Google Maps Api v2 Android Error Google Maps Api v2 Android Error Google Maps Api v2 Android Error Google Maps Api v2 Android Error Google Maps Api v2 Android Error Google Maps Api v2 Android Error Google Maps Api v2 Android Error Google Maps Api v2 Android Error Google Maps Api v2 Android Error Google Maps Api v2 Android Error Google Maps Api v2 Android Error

Comment: The minSdk attribute in Manifest is set to be 16, so you cannot run the app on Android versions < 4.1.x (Jelly Bean)

Comment: and instead of the repeated 'Google Maps Api v2 Android Error ', the error log will be welcome

Comment: yes. When run on my Emulator ( Nexus 5 API 17 Android 4.2 APIs armeabi v7a and use Host GPU arm) show this message :This app won't run unless you update google Play Serice. When tap on  UPDATE  -> Error :

Comment: Clean up your question and add the logcat to the question, not the comments. This is a mess.

Comment: have you downloaded the "Google APIs" version from SDK manager? And are you using it in your emulator?

Comment: Also it is better to check before doing the initializations for the map whether the googleplayservices is installed. Update that part in your code. The documentation is given well on the official page https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: i have installed all Google APIs

Comment: Ok you installed it, but are you using it in the emulator?

Comment: YES https://www.dropbox.com/s/pb8f99jxxa71rsv/Schermata%202015-04-15%20alle%2018.29.16.png?dl=0

Comment: only work on NEXUS 5 API 21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because version 2 of the Google Maps Android API requires OpenGL ES version 2, you must add a  element as a child of the  manifest element in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-feature   android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
  android:required="true"/>
```

This notifies external services of the requirement. In particular, it has the effect of preventing Google Play Store from displaying your app on devices that don't support OpenGL ES version 2.

You have not made this addition in your manifest. This is required for the version 2. It might be because of this that the peculiar situation of app running on some device is happening.

In your code make sure that you put the code for checking whether play services is installed as well. Follow the steps in the official documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android

Comment: Edit the question and post the new code with the changes incorporated

Comment: Are you sure that the device other than Nexus5 that you are using supports OpenGL ES V2

Comment: I had already added this code <uses-feature   android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
  android:required="true"/>  in AndroidManifest.

Comment: I have tested the App on many real Android devices with android 4.1 and 4.2.2 but it didn't work

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25809435/google-play-services-out-of-date-requires-5089000-but-found-3136130  the error here is similar to the one you are getting in your error log

Comment: Thanks but the problem is not the Emulator